# How to change the field dynamically in Oracle Forms Builder 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to change the field dynamically in Oracle Forms Builder 10g?

Example: If I am have 3 list items like ED,CESS,SHEC etc. Suppose if I need add one more list item. it will show dynamically in form builder.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to go the PJC way http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-1931073.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make fields dynamically in Oracle Forms Builder.
What you can do is the following:
In a block you can have for example 15 fields and you place them on the canvas. All on the same position.

In the pre-form trigger you see how many fields you need and you use set_item_property to make them visible true or false and also enabled true or false.
You can also set the position using set_item_property by counting how many fields you got and by testing out the layout, for example each field you want to display is 15 or 20 px lower then the first field, and so on until you have all your fields displayed.